# New to blender; fire + smoke not rendering

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, node-editor

Being new to Blender (version 2.79), I've tried to do the Bezier curve tutorial. Along the way, I wanted to add some smoke and fire effects to the sphere / ball in the middle of the figure.

While things show up fine in the 3D Viewport, rendering does not seem to display the flame effect. Attached is the screenshot of the node setup for the Smoke Domain Material. Any insights on what I did wrong which caused the flame effect to not be displayed in the render preview?

Link to the Blend file I've been practicing with: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49714

[image: Smoke Domain Material Node setup]

Comment: The node setup is fine apart from using color to fac instead of fac to fac from flame attribute, but that should only loose you some detail but still render the flame.

Comment: Try getting rid of Clamp in Math node, it's not needed there.

Comment: Your multiply values seem a bit high but you should see something. Try adding some strong lights to your scene. I think the best results I get with fire are when I add big emission planes to the scene.